# How well is 802.1x-2010 generally supported?

Tags: network-access-control

I have often come across 802.1x (2004) deployments in internal company networks. The problem with that protocol is that after the handshake, the network traffic is not encrypted. This means that, for example, if you put a hub between a machine that is able to authenticate via 802.1x and the network outlet, you just have to wait until the authentication process is done, spoof the MAC address of the computer (you get a copy of all packets on a hub), and you have access to the network. There are even [products that automate that process](https://www.pwnieexpress.com/product-documentation/).

Now customers keep asking me what to do about this. Then I say that there is the [802.1x-2010 Standard](http://www.ieee802.org/1/pages/802.1x-2010.html) which addresses that specific problem. The question I cannot answer, however, is how well 802.1x-2010 is supported generally.

Now my question is: **How well is 802.1x-2010 supported in common operating systems and network equipment for enterprise environments?** Does anyone have practical experience with the deployment of 802.1x-2010?

I just cannot find any statements from the major operating system and network equipment manufacturers regarding 802.1x-2010 (only 802.1x-2004).

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to search for "macsec support". I'm getting a lot of results.

Comment: I'm still unable to find out whethere or not, for example, Windows 8 supports MACsec. Are you?

Comment: Network cards do. That's the important part.